# List of linked tuple to nested dict

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, nested-lists

I have a list of tuples. This could look like this:

```
tuple_list = [
             ('species',  'flower'),
             ('flower', 'dorsal flower'),
             ('dorsal flower', 'pink'),
             ('pink', 'white'),
             ('pink', 'greenish'),
             ('species', 'branch'), 
    ]
```

**Note**: The tuples are not in order and in this example, they could also vary in order. The 'deepness' can also vary.

I would like to create a dict of dict that would look like this:

```
dod = {'species': {'branch':{},'flower': {'dorsal flower':{'pink': {'white':{}}, 'greenish':{}}}}}
```

In this case I want the species at top level, as it has no items that 'contain' species'. E.g. species contains 'flower' and 'branch' and so on.

I feel this entire process can be wrapped in a simple recursive function (e.g. `yield from`) instead of writing an elaborative for loop that iterates over all values.

In the end, I want to use this function to create a list of lists that contains the proper values as a list (Kudos to @Stef for this function):

```
def undict_to_lists(d, acc = []):
    if d == {}:
        yield acc
    else:
        for k, v in d.items():
            yield from undict_to_tuples(v, acc + [k,])
```

This would result in the following:

```
print(list(undict_to_lists(dod)))
[['species', 'branch'],
 ['species', 'flower', 'dorsal flower', 'pink', 'white'],
 ['species', 'flower', 'dorsal flower', 'greenish']]
```

Thanks for thinking along! All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Given that the input is not necessarily in order, what should happen if it contains, for example, both `('pink', 'white')` and `('white', 'pink')`? Also, given that the input is not necessarily in order, in the original input, what is the rule that tells you that `('species',  'flower')` gives the root of the tree?

Comment: As for now ```('pink', 'white')``` and ```('white', 'pink')``` should not be possible when I generate the data. And if so, I'll raise an exception. The species is always the root of the tree. In the end, I use these data not as graphs, but I convert them to process them into text snippets for zero-shot learning for a deep learning model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another alternative (loosely based on @trincot answer) that uses a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to simplify the code slightly and which figures out the root of the tree as it goes through the list of tuples:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)
root = tuple_list[0][0]            # first parent value
for parent, child in tuple_list:
    d[parent][child] = d[child]
    if root == child:
        root = parent


result = { root : d[root] }
```

Output:

```
{
    "species": {
        "branch": {},
        "flower": {
            "dorsal flower": {
                "pink": {
                    "greenish": {},
                    "white": {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I see what you mean, this version does seems to work no matter the order of the tuples. I do expect the data generation functions make sure the tuples always start with ```"species"```, but I am unsure of this. Thanks @Nick!

Answer (score 2):

You could first create a dictionary key (with `{}` as value) for each key that occurs in the input. Then iterate those tuples to find the value that corresponds to the start key, and populate the sub dictionary with the end key, and the subdictionary that corresponds to that end key.

Finally, derive which is the root by excluding all those nodes that are children.

```
tuple_list = [('species',  'flower'), ('flower', 'dorsal flower'), ('dorsal flower', 'pink'),('pink', 'white'),('pink', 'greenish'),('species', 'branch')]

d = { key: {} for pair in tuple_list for key in pair }
for start, end in tuple_list:
    d[start][end] = d[end]

root = None
for key in set(d.keys()).difference(end for _, end in tuple_list):
    root = d[key]

print(root)
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you sir! This seems like a very elegant way of solving this problem! I have no clue which answer is the best, this one or @Samwise. I do like preventing if/else statements to be honest, like you did!

Answer (score 2):

```
tuple_list = [
    ('species',  'flower'),
    ('flower', 'dorsal flower'),
    ('dorsal flower', 'pink'),
    ('pink', 'white'),
    ('pink', 'greenish'),
    ('species', 'branch'), 
]

# Create the nested dict,  using a "master" dict 
# to quickly look up nodes in the nested dict.
nested_dict, master_dict = {}, {}
for a, b in tuple_list:
    if a not in master_dict:
        nested_dict[a] = master_dict[a] = {}
    master_dict[a][b] = master_dict[b] = {}

# Flatten into lists.
def flatten_dict(d):
    if not d:
        return [[]]
    return [[k] + f for k, v in d.items() for f in flatten_dict(v)]

print(flatten_dict(nested_dict))
#[['species', 'flower', 'dorsal flower', 'pink', 'white'], 
# ['species', 'flower', 'dorsal flower', 'pink', 'greenish'],
# ['species', 'branch']]
```

Comment: Both answers (@trincot) do generate the desired result! I was actually thinking the same direction as this with an if statement to check whether the items already exist within the dict. But to be honest, I have no clue which is now the preferred answer.

Comment: @Robert this solution *only* works if the entries in the tuple are in order.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative :

```
def find_node( tree, parent, child ):
    if parent in tree:
        tree[parent][child] = {}
        return True

    for node in tree.values():
        if find_node( node, parent, child ):
            return True
    
    # new node
    tree[parent] = { child : {} }
    
root = {}
for parent, child in tuple_list:
    find_node( root, parent, child )
```